# Call webservice from Windows Phone library

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Regards,

I am trying to call a webservice from within the library of windows phone application that I am creating, however I have a weird problem and I hope that you can help me.

First of all I have the following code on my Application main page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Library;
using System.Threading;

namespace Host
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Class1.AsyncCall test = new AsyncCall();
        test.Call("0002145", 51);


    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
}
```

My `AsyncCall` class is in my library and it has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using Library;
using Library.WebserviceRemote;


namespace Library
{

public class AsyncCallWS
{

WebserviceCall com = new WebserviceCall();
com.methodOne("methodOne", "1221", 122);
} 
}
```

My `WebserviceCall` is another class in library and the method that is called looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
//using System.ServiceModel;
using Library.WebserviceRemote;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace Library
{

//[DebuggerNonUserCode]
public class WebserviceCall
{

public void methodOne(String Method, String param1, int param2)
{
    WebserviceRemote client = new WebserviceRemote ();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I am in methodOne " + param1 + param2);

    client.methodOneOnServiceCompleted += new EventHandler<methodOneOnServiceCompletedEventArgs>(client_methodOneOnServiceCompleted);
    client.methodOneOnServiceAsync("1221", 122);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After call to webservice ");
}

private void client_methodOneOnServiceCompleted(object sender, methodOneOnServiceCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the response " + e.Result);

}
}
}
```

Well the problem is that the method `client_methodOneOnServiceCompleted` is never read, the application never gets in it so I cannot get the response from webservice. I think it has something due to the `EventHandler` since this is all done in library not the applications page.

However, I am not aware why it doesn't get in that method. Furthermore, there are no errors and everything is there on output except this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the response " + e.Result);
```

Another notice: this code works like a charm when the call is made from within application itself but I really need to make webservice call from library, so please help :)

PS: this is all tested in emulator 7.0

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point within your code and then running it and seeing where it is throwing out, or you could put it in a try catch and see if it throws an error further up the stack

Comment: I put a break point but it doesnt even come to the method:     private void client_methodOneOnServiceCompleted(object sender, methodOneOnServiceCompletedEventArgs e). And I have put a try and catch but it works fine since it doesn't throw any error it simply doesn't enter the method I stated.

Comment: have you tried declaring the eventhandler outside of the method and then reference it like that, it seems like it is not iniatilised when you run it from the lib

Comment: I have tried that too, but it won't let me it gives two erros. One is that a client is a field but used as a type, and another is client_methodOneOnServiceCompleted is used as a method but used as a type.

Comment: So just to confirm you have declared it at the top like

EventHandler event = new EventHandler<methodOneOnServiceCompletedEventArgs>()

Then tried doing it like 

client.methodOneOnServiceCompleted += event(client_methodOneOnServiceCompleted)

I dont mean to sound patronizing just with out being there to see what you have tried I need to check everything

Comment: Ask whatever info you need, in my interest is to solve this too :) So whatever you wanna make sure please feel free to ask. And, yes I did on that way too but the same error appears.

Comment: I will edit my question so you can see my whole file structure

Comment: To be honest mate I cannot see what is wrong lol, it should just work, I am not at my dev machine at the moment so when I am in an hour I will build a project and step through see if I can find a problem, obviously if someone else gets here first lucky you lol otherwise I will be back once I can build + debug

Comment: Thank you mate i will wait for your answer :) yea i dunno what can be a problem either it just ignores the last method from last class :/

Comment: Hi mate, 
I had a look last night and cannot replicate your problem. I have got a spare hour this morning and will keep looking... hope to have a update for you later

Comment: Thank you for your response. So it is working fine? Just to confirm you have created Windows Phone apliaction and then a added a component to it from which you added service reference and is calling webservice?

Comment: Yep I literally copied what you had written and then added it as a service reference, One difference is maybe I have resharper from jetbrains installed and it tends t automatically set references. You can get a free evaluation version. It maybe an idea to install that as it catches alot of errors visual studio normally misses http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Ok I just wanted to check because Library is added as Reference to my Host application and the classes and methods for calling webservice are in my Library. I really dunno what is the problem with this code :( The worst thing is that there are no errors it simply doesn't call or get in the last method to retrieve result from webservice.

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is try setting it up as a web service in IIS or local machine and try to reference that

Comment: Can you provide a simple repro for this issue?